# combine two date in two separate list and and two value with two separate list corresponding value in python

Tags: python

I have 4 list 2 dates with 2 value then I make one unique date and I need sum of two date's value [here is a image now i need sum with the corresponding  date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoKmL.jpg)
the result should be `2020-01-01 = 0` and `2020-01-04 = 56.6911`. but my code give me the sum of the first element of index value thats is wrong with date.

```py
for fovar_srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt, fovar_uniq_inv_date_list,fovar_uniq_pos_date_list in zip(srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt,uniq_inv_date_list,uniq_pos_date_list):
            # print(fovar_srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt)
            if fovar_srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt == fovar_uniq_inv_date_list or fovar_srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt == fovar_uniq_pos_date_list :
                for nestf_inv_magin,nestf_amount_list in zip(inv_margin_list,amount_list):
                    final_both_amount = nestf_inv_magin + nestf_amount_list
                    print('sum of value',final_both_amount)
            break
```

output

```py
sum of value 22.6911
sum of value 79.8855
sum of value 4170.0231
sum of value -7.48
sum of value 2155.55
sum of value 852.357
sum of value 257.84
sum of value 314.88
sum of value 7814.597
sum of value 637.147
sum of value 813.6275
```

Comment: Can you post your input data in string format? Also could you elaborate a bit on the logic and also put your desired output in text format. I understand- input is a list(s) - and output also should be a list- just filtered/transformed input...

Comment: how can i filter list. please look at the image in question. now I merge and get unique date list. Now I have one unique date list and two lists with value. now i need check. print the value with the corresponding date
print('date 1',uniq_pos_date_list)
        print('values1',amount_list)
        print('date 2', uniq_inv_date_list)
        print('values2', inv_margin_list)
        print('date1+date2 make unique date',srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt)
        print('need help, sum of values 2 according to date')

Comment: Sorry, still not clear - would be way easier if you would put your input and desired output in writing, in text format.

Comment: thanks for your respons
print('dt 1',uniq_pos_date_list)
 print('val1',amount_list)
 print('dt 2', uniq_inv_date_list)
 print('vl2', inv_margin_list)
 print('date1+date2 make unique date',srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt)
 print(' sum values 2')
output
 date 1 ['2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07']
values1 [22.6911, 45.88549999999999, 34.0231, 8.52]
date 2 ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07']
values2 [0, 34, 4136, -16]
dt1+dt2 make unique date ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06]
requred list
output should be [0, 56.6911, 45.88, 4136,]